# How to pass ejs message into angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, ejs

I am doing a mean app project and right now so far all my backend work from, express, passport and the csrf token and the flash message.

The tricky part now is how to get it to the client side and I am using angular and Ionic frame work

How do I pass flash message into angular? I can't figure out how or maybe I am doing it wrong? 
Is there anyway to do it?
Like I dont know how to do it in app.js please help

[image: This is what is happening]

If you guys need my app.js or look into my code a little bit more, please comment away

This is my html

```
 <div id="createaccount">
<a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-light" a href="#/signup"></a>
<h1 class="hidden">Creating Account</h1>
<img src="../img/logo.png" alt=logo id="logo">
<div id="footer">
<div class="imageHolder">
<img src="../img/email.png" alt=mail id="emailIcon">
<img src="../img/key.png" alt="key" id="keyIcon">
</div>

<%- if (hasErrors) {%>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
 <%- messages.forEach(function(message){ %>
   <p><-%= message %></p>
 <%- });%>
 </div>
 <-% }%>

 <div class="list list-inset" id="form">
  <form action="register" method="post">
    <label class="item item-input"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input" id="passform"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken%>"/>

   <div> 
   <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" a href="#/questions" button class="button" id="submitbutton"></a>
  </div>
   </div>

    </form>
   </div>

     </div>
```

Comment: is this an HTML file or an EJS file?  your screenshot makes it look like it is an HTML partial, which is not parsed by EJS on the server.

Comment: this is the html for angular, i have ejs for the backend. right now your are looking at the ionic framework showing the html partial

Comment: right, so this is an `.html` file then?  if that's the case, then you can't use ejs in it....

Comment: is there another way to get the express flash working? because  need the token for my app

Comment: make your partial an `.ejs` file would *probably* work, but really you shouldn't use a client template engine and a server template engine in the same app, it creates potential security loopholes.

Comment: i tried doing that and it didnt work :/

Comment: Angular is a Single Page Application framework, it is designed to completely function in the client without making any calls back to the server.  Template partials are retrieved via ajax calls, which may not be processed through EJS.  On top of that, EJS assumes that each page will make a server request for the next page, where Angular assumes you only want to fetch data from the server, not a new fully rendered page.  CSRF tokens don't make sense for angular, since it doesn't make page requests the way a traditional forms webpage might.